# How do classes with descriptors have their instance attributes resolved with the descriptor's methods?

Tags: python, class, python-descriptors

I'm confused why instance attributes retrieved through after instance instantiation or set during instance construction are done so via the descriptor.

For example, assume we have the following descriptor and class.

**Descriptor**

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class Positive:

   def  __init__(self):
      self._instance_data = WeakKeyDictionary()

   def __get__(self, instance, owner):
      return self._instance_data[instance]

   def __set__(self, instance, value):
      if value <= 0:
         raise ValueError(f'Value {value} is not positive')
      self._instance_data[instance] = value

   def __delete__(self, instance):
      raise AttributeError('Cannot delete attribute!')
```

**Class**

```
class Planet:

   def __init__(self, name, mass_kilograms):
      self.name = name
      self.mass_kilograms= mass_kilograms

   mass_kilograms = Positive()
```

Now we create an instance of Planet and retrieve its mass.

```
pluto = Planet(name = 'Pluto', mass_kilograms = 1.305e22) 
# The above line is doing Positive.__set__(self, pluto, 1.305e22) under the hood.
# It is NOT doing self.mass_kilograms = 1.305e22. In fact, all of the instance
# attributes are stored in the descriptor Positive's _instance_data
m = pluto.mass_kilograms # m = Positive.__get__(self, pluto, Planet)
```

I have no idea why `Positive.__get__` is called, given that is is a class attribute. Can someone please explain? Whats even more confusing is how `Positive.__set__` intercepts the direct assignment of the constructor parameter `mass_kilograms`.

Thanks!

Comment: As written, your example produces errors/exceptions. Please correct.

Comment: `how Positive.__set__ intercepts the direct assignment of the constructor parameter mass_kilograms` - what makes you think that is happening?

Comment: @wwii Done. Editted.

Comment: @wwii `mass_kilograms` binds an instance of the Positive descriptor to the class Planet. The call to __init__ is then assigning to an instance attribute, but this assignment is ACTUALLY invoking a method __set__ on the descriptor object. I'm not sure why though. I'm watching a video that is explaining,but I don't understand...

I know that `Positive.__set__` is intercepting the mass_kilograms passed during construction (in `__init__`) because when I create a new object as such `uranus = Planet('Uranus', -1)`, a ValueError is thrown. It's essentially doing `Positive.__set__(self, uranus, -1)`

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what the question is?  descriptors work this way because this is how descriptors work.  intercepting instance attributes is exactly what they're _for_.

Comment: @Eevee But how does it do so? `self.mass_kilograms` is an instance attribute, and `mass_kilograms` is a class attribute. How does `mass_kilograms`, a `Positive` object (class attribute) reach through `__init__`, make sure the value I'm setting isn't below 0, before proceeding to store its value in the class attribute `mass_kilograms` WeakKeyDictionary?

Comment: `mass_kilograms` is *not* an instance attribute. It's a class attribute whose value is a descriptor, so `self.mass_kilograms = mass_kilograms` desugars to a call to `Planet.mass_kilograms.__set__(self, mass_kilograms)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mass_kilograms` is not an instance attribute. It is a class attribute bound to an instance of the descriptor `Planet`.

```
class Planet:

   def __init__(self, name, mass_kilograms):
      self.name = name
      self.mass_kilograms= mass_kilograms
     a

   mass_kilograms = Positive()  # This creates a class attribute
```

Because `Positive` defines `__set__`, it is a data descriptor. According to the descriptor how-to:

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`. The implementation works through a precedence chain that **gives data descriptors priority over instance variables**, instance variables priority over non-data descriptors, and assigns lowest priority to `__getattr__()` if provided. The full C implementation can be found in `PyObject_GenericGetAttr()` in `Objects/object.c`.

In `Planet.__init__`, the assignment to this class attribute triggers a call to the `__set__` method of the descriptor, as if you had written

```
def __init__(self, name, mass_kilograms):
    self.name = name
    self.mass_kilograms.__set__(self, mass_kilograms)
```

Even more basically, the last line is equivalent to

```
Positive.__set__(type(self).mass_kilograms, self, mass_kilograms)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify (put simply), does the following: `The implementation works through a precedence chain that gives data descriptors priority over instance variables` mean that Python will look for any class attributes with the same name as the instance attribute, verifying that they are data descriptors, before assigning `mass_kilograms` to `self.mass_kilograms`? By this I mean that, if Python finds a data descriptor as a class attribute, it will resolve to the data descriptor as opposed to directly assigning the value to the instance's attribute?

Comment: In this case, it's not even an instance attribute *yet*; the instance attribute would only be created if a class attribute by that name was a non-data descriptor.

Comment: Perfect, got it. I continued reading and noticed the precedence in attribute lookup precedence (1. Data descriptors in class, 2. Instance attributes in `__dict__`, 3. non-data descriptors in class)